# " 'default parameter' is not defined" in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am going to attempt to post this without having to share my 1500 lines of code for a react component that I've built. Here is the general structure of my component, like any other:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import d3 from "d3";

class presComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { ... }
}

someHelperFunction(paramA="blue", paramB="red") { ... }

componentDidMount() {
    this.someHelperFunction(paramA="blue", paramB="red")
}

render() {
   ...
```

After my constructor I have a number of functions that I used to organize my code, that are called in the lifecycle methods (DidMount and DidUpdate, for the most part). Some of my helper functions have default parameters, in this case *someHelperFunction* has parameters paramA and paramB, with default values blue and red.

This component is a presentational component, and I call it from within one of my main container components. When I do, I receive the following errors:

```
Line 1735:  'paramA' is not defined       no-undef
Line 1735:  'paramB' is not defined       no-undef
```

Line 1735 in my code is the calling of the function inside of componentDidMount, so the following line:

```
this.someHelperFunction(paramA="blue", paramB="red")
```

Why is this the case. Even though in my example I set the parameter values to their default values, even if I do not use the default values I receive this error. Any help here is appreciated, it feels like I don't understand the use of default parameters for a function in javascript / react.

Thanks!

Comment: this works for my component in codepen. it only is an issue right now that I'm trying to create the component actually in my react app. how should i be doing this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.someHelperFunction(paramA="blue", paramB="red")
```

this does 3 things

1. Assign "blue" to paramA (in the calling context, no relation to the argument names in the function)
2. Assign "red" to paramB (in the calling context, no relation to the argument names in the function)
3. call the function with arguments "blue", and "red"

Now, if you are in strict mode, `paramA` and `paramB` need to be existing variables to not get the warning/error - again, this instance of `paramA` and `paramB` are totally unrelated to the parameter names in the function

you could just as well have

```
someHelperFunction(paramA="blue", paramB="red") { ... }

this.someHelperFunction(someRandomWord="blue", anotherRandomWord="red")
```

and you'd face the same error (except the error would say that `someRandomWord` and `anotherRandomWord` are not defined

Comment: yeah i just took out paramA and paramB in the function call. that style works in other programming languages that i use more frequently, hence the original reason I thought it would work here (plus it worked in codepen for some odd reason)

Comment: well, it only generates the warning/error in a code linter or an error in javascript "strict mode" - your codepen must've been "loose" mode javascript (the default)

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
someHelperFunction(paramA, paramB) { ... }

componentDidMount() {
    this.someHelperFunction("blue", "red")
}
```

Comment: why would he want to remove the default value?